# get specified value in the xml jquery

Tags: jquery

Good Day!

How can i get the value of Id(2943) using Jquery

```
    <ae:return>
        <ae:item>
           <ae:id xsi:type="ae:ItemIdentifier">
              <ae:displayName>03884</ae:displayName>
              <ae:id>2943</ae:id>
           </ae:id>
           <ae:itemType>Choices</ae:itemType>
           <ae:project xsi:type="ae:ProjectIdentifier">
              <ae:displayName>Choices</ae:displayName>
              <ae:id>94</ae:id>
           </ae:project>
        </ae:item>
    <ae:return>
```

Comment: jQuery isn't designed to read xml. You're going to want to use a different tool.

Comment: do you get this as a response for an ajax call?

Comment: jQuery is perfectly designed to read XML, it even has it's own $.parseXML method, but for that you'll need valid XML, and this doesn't look valid ?